# Creating IAM members in GCP throws error The size of the policy is too large

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

When I try to create a new IAM user in GCP, I get the following  error

```
Request "Create IAM Members roles/dns.admin serviceAccount:dns-mngt-sa-prod@pprojectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
for \"project \\\"projectId\\\"\"" returned error:
 Error applying IAM policy for project "projectId": Error setting IAM policy for project "projectId": googleapi: Error 400:
 The size of the policy is too large.
 Consider removing or merging some of the bindings or if using conditions remove 
any lengthy conditions., badRequest
```

Above shown is the output from terraform apply command. When I try to use gcloud cli, I get a similar output as well
When I try to create it through GCP console, it just shows "backend error"

Comment: Could you share the terraform code with sensitive information left out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you hit one of the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas) of IAM. All the bindings you specified in Terraform are uploaded every time you perform an update or create. As the error says you are probably creating a lot of bindings that could be merged together. I suggest trying to find which quota limit you are reaching and why, here are some debugging commands:

Number of iam bindings:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID --format=json | jq '.bindings | length'
```

Total size of the bindings:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID --format=json | jq '.bindings' > iam.json
ls -l iam.json
```

Occurence of each member in all the bindings:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID --format=json | jq ".bindings[].members" | jq -s flatten
```

Then, you could reduce the number of bindings by merging. For example, this binding:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:user-a@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/owner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:user-b@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/owner"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "BwUjMhCsNvY=",
  "version": 1
}
```

Could be merged to this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:user-b@example.com",
        "user:user-a@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/owner"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "BwUjMhCsNvY=",
  "version": 1
}
```

Comment: it is not that obvious how the limits are calculated. I had 434 bindings as per the command. However, after removing 2 IAM users from console it worked

Comment: I understand, but you could have hit one of the other limits. For example, there can be 1500 appearances of members across all bindings. Thus you could also count all the members in the bindings to see if you reached the maximum. Most likely, removing the users, removed them from the bindings as well, thus temporarily "curing the symptoms".